# MySQL attribute database

Tags: sql, mysql, join, normalization

I have an attribute database. Each attribute value is stored in a table with an ID to its parent attribute.

In a stand alone table I would write an SQL statement that would pull data

```
WHERE username = '' AND domain = ''
```

In the attribute table as each value is stored as a separate row, I can not do this.. I have a join that allows me to bring back one value + result (see below), however i need a result based on 2 criteria as shown above..

```
SELECT upa.value, up.status, u.status
  FROM user_product up, product_attribute pa, product p, user u, user_product_attribute upa

 WHERE pa.attribute_name = 'username'
   AND pa.product_attribute_id = upa.product_attribute_id
   AND pa.product_id = p.product_id
   AND u.user_id = up.user_id
   AND up.user_product_id = upa.user_product_id

   AND p.product_name = 'email'
   AND upa.value      = 'exampleuser'
```

I presume i would need to join the above able again in some sort of union? Any input would be helpful..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't use implicit join syntax. A second set of joins is needed to get a second attribute.

```
SELECT upa1.value, upa2.value, up1.status, u1.status 
  FROM product p
    /* These joins get attribute/value for 'username' attribute */
    INNER JOIN product_attribute pa1
      ON p.product_id = pa1.product_id
        AND pa1.attribute_name = 'username'
    INNER JOIN user_product_attribute upa1
      ON pa1.product_attribute_id = upa1.product_attribute_id
    INNER JOIN user_product up1
      ON upa1.user_product_id = up1.user_product_id
    INNER JOIN user u1
      ON up1.user_id = u1.user_id 
    /* These joins get attribute/value for 'domain' attribute */  
    INNER JOIN user_product_attribute upa2 
      ON upa1.user_product_id = upa2.user_product_id
    INNER JOIN product_attribute pa2
      ON upa2.product_attribute_id = pa2.product_attribute_id            
        AND pa2.attribute_name = 'domain'
  WHERE p.product_name = 'email'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input.. The problem i see however, is there could be many domains, not just one.. so doing a join like that would bring back 1:* instead of a 1:1..

Comment: If there are many domains for a given product, how do you decide which one you want returned? In other words, what other criteria would you use to break the tie between multiple domains?

Comment: @Lee: Updated my answer based on your comments to @ar about the common `user_product_id` value.

Comment: Thanks for that, worked a treat.. I can also see where i was thinking incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to repeat all of the joins twice to get both attributes. It's not pretty especially if you need more than 2 or 3 attributes at one time.

```
SELECT upa.value, up.status, u.status
FROM user_product up
JOIN user u    ON u.user_id = up.user_id

-- Join to get attribute 'username'
JOIN user_product_attribute upa1 ON up.user_product_id = upa1.user_product_id
JOIN product_attribute pa1 ON pa1.product_attribute_id = upa1.product_attribute_id
JOIN product p1                  ON pa1.product_id = p1.product_id

-- Join to get attribute 'domain'    
JOIN user_product_attribute upa2 ON up.user_product_id = upa2.user_product_id
JOIN product_attribute pa2 ON pa2.product_attribute_id = upa2.product_attribute_id
JOIN product p2                  ON pa2.product_id = p2.product_id

WHERE pa1.attribute_name = 'domain'
  AND p1.product_name = 'email'
  AND upa1.value      = 'exampledomain.com'

  AND pa2.attribute_name = 'username'
  AND p2.product_name = 'email'
  AND upa2.value      = 'exampleuser'
;
```

Comment: `Product` is common for both sets of attributes (`product.product_name = 'email'`), so that table should only be referenced once in the query.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input.. The problem i see however, is there could be many domains, not just one.. so doing a join like that would bring back 1:* instead of a 1:1..

Comment: @Lee, in that case you will need to update your question with the logic you want to use to select the records. For example, do you want to search for records where any of the associated domain records match or some other logic?

Comment: Values are linked to a user product via a user_product_id within the user_product_attribute table.. So a domain + username combo should share an identical user_product_id  value.