# MySQL concat multiple rows into a single row

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, concatenation

I have a query that returns multiple rows such as below in MySQL:

```
attribute_name  value
----------------------------------------
username          emailuser
domain          mydomain.com
```

My Required output is as follows:

```
username       domain
-----------------------------
emailuser     mydomain.com
```

Current SQL:

```
    SELECT pa2.attribute_name, upa2.value
      FROM product p

INNER JOIN product_attribute pa ON p.product_id = pa.product_id
       AND pa.attribute_name = 'alias'

INNER JOIN user_product_attribute upa ON pa.product_attribute_id upa.product_attribute_id

INNER JOIN user_product_attribute upa2 ON upa.user_product_id = upa2.user_product_id

INNER JOIN product_attribute pa2 ON pa2.product_attribute_id = upa2.product_attribute_id
    AND pa2.attribute_name
    IN (
    'username', 'domain'
    )

WHERE p.product_name = 'email'
AND upa.value = 'emailalias@domainalias'
```

I have been looking at group_concat, but i think that is the wrong path.. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you already have the answer to this in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934300/mysql-attribute-database). Just modify the first line of [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934300/mysql-attribute-database/4934506#4934506) to be: `SELECT upa1.value as username, upa2.value as domain`

Comment: Hey Joe, thanks for taking another look at one of my problems.. upa1 is used to pull back valies matching an alias.. upa2 brings back 2 values being username and domain as seperate rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with `group_concat`. The following query will be slow but for a small table, that might not matter so much.

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(`attribute_name`='username', `value`,'')) AS `username`,
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(`attribute_name`='domain', `value`, '')) AS `domain`,
FROM (your old table or the select query)
GROUP BY `attribute_name`
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, worked a treat.. I didn't realise you could use conditional statements like that.. I might have to search for a faster method but its put me on the right track i believe..